# Deploy website to github and editing online and showing blank

Tags: git, web, jekyll, web-deployment, github-pages

After I'd pushed site made by jekyll to Github repo via git. my site was published it was ok.After I did some changes inside Github online for one of my files [Halim.md](https://github.com/HalimHamidov/halim.github.io/blob/master/Halim.md) [Update Halim.md](https://github.com/HalimHamidov/halim.github.io/commit/4e3dac0aea3e6661bc2277bba75eb305e5e020d9)
my link got blank. after some actions now the site showing this message error again:

---

404
There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.

If you're trying to publish one, read the full documentation to learn how to set up GitHub Pages for your repository, organization, or user account.

GitHub Status — @githubstatus

---

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Github Pages repository for https://github.com/HalimHamidov must be named https://github.com/HalimHamidov/halimhamidov.github.io. Rename the repository, push and wait until Github update Pages.